# Couldn't init canvas using fabricjs + vuejs (this.lowerCanvasEl.getContext is not a function)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fabricjs

I'm trying to init canvas in vuejs component. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/55338/

I init canvas in `mounted` hook, which means the DOM is available. Also I can see that fabric stars doing its job by making `lower-canvas` div, but then it throws:

`this.lowerCanvasEl.getContext is not a function`

Couldn't figure out what's the problem. I already use fabric in my project, and never got such error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a problem of Vue. If you take all Vue code away, the problem persists.

**fabric** needs to be mounted on a `<canvas>` element, not a `<div>`.

[Updated fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/eywraw8t/55623/)

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",

  mounted: function() {
    new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
      width: 500,
      height: 500
    })
  }
})
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.2.3/fabric.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the hell I couldn't notice it myself. I owe you two beers :)

Comment: Hahaha!  always glad to be of help! :D

Comment: The fun is that I already used fabric a lot in my project, but just didn't notice I used wrong tag... Maybe you also know why canvas can't catch drag&drop events, https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/56370/ ?

Comment: Those listeners on that fiddle are bound to the canvas, not to the `#draggable` div, is that it?

Comment: Yeah, I want to listen when I drop the red rectangle on canvas, and I didn't manage to do it both in jsfiddle and in my project

Comment: The thing is fabric changes the DOM when activated on an element. To be pure, you'd have to check how they handle drag&drop. If you want to "force" in, you could do something like: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/eywraw8t/56443/